# Using post-baby-bath balneum water for my plants

Tags: watering

We have a new baby, and we wash him with water with a few drops of balneum oil (on about a bucket's worth of water). I'd like to "reuse" the water afterwards on my many plants, if possible. Will it be harmful for them in the short or long run?

Just to clarify - I plan on using it on ornamental plants, not vegetables, fruits or herbs.

The ingredients are as follows: Glycine Soia Oil, Laureth-4, Oleamide DEA, Parfum (Benzyl Alcohol, Benzyl Salicylate, Geraniol, Benzyl Benzoae, Citronellol, Limonene), Propylene Glycol, BHT, Ascorbyl Palimitate, Citric Acid.

Answer (score 3):

Provided the plants are not in pots, and provided you spread it around, not concentrating it in one area every time, it should be okay - but I wouldn't recommend it long term, nor more frequently than once a week on each area of soil. If there's rain in between, all the better, it'll help dilute things a bit.

If you notice ill effects on the plants, stop using it (I'm aware I'm stating the perfectly b...y obvious, but feel the need to say it anyway!)